# How to abort git add -p discarding changes?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-add

I ran `git add` on some files, constituting a logical separate set of changes, made other changes to them and extracted another logical set of changes using `git add -p`. Half way through, I realize that I have not committed the previous set, yet.

The interactive help of `git add -p` only gives the following options:

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,s,e,?]? ?
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk nor any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

How can I reset the added patches?

Answer (score 5):

`git add -p` stages changes without storing a history, which could be used to revert the addition. You can however use **`git reset -p`** or **`git reset --patch`** to unstage the changes. A procedure would look something line the following:

- enter `q`
  to exit the interactive `git add -p`
- `git reset -p`
  to reset all changes that were added by mistake
- `git commit`
  to commit the first changeset
- `git add -p`
  again, adding changes to a new second commit
- `git commit`
  to commit the second commit